# How to modify inner text in class Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this element, and i want to change text inside class by Selenium driver
from New York to Paris. How can i do that?

Element:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="get_city_select">New York</a>
```

This is my code but it doesn't work:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("get_city_select")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'Paris'", element)
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the `attribute`, use the below code with specific xpath :  `//a[text()='New York']`

**code :**

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='New York']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'Paris'", element)
```